# I want to open new tab in browser when I press on asp.net hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, hyperlink

I want to open new tab or pop window after clicking on the hyper link and this window contain the navigator URL ?

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Path")%>'>
                        <asp:Image ID="product_image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Path")%>'
                            Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                    </asp:HyperLink>
```

this code open the url in same tab I want it in another tab or pop up window or any new idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Target-attribute:

```
 <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" />
```

It will open in a new window, or tab, depending on browser setting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to append `target="_blank"` to your `<asp:HyperLink />` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" runat="server" Target="_blank">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Output HTML:

```
<a id="HyperLink1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">HyperLink</a>
```

Above markup will behave like this:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/6qCYY/
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you can add a target attribute to your markup.
If you need to decide dynamically during page loading should that page open in a separate tab or not, then you can use code block as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... 
    if (ShouldLinkOpenInNewWindow())
    {
        HyperLink1.Target = "_blank";
    }
    // ...
}
```